# python how do I add string to json array

Tags: python, arrays, json

So I have this data.json file

```
{
  "names": [
    {
      "firstnames": ["Jim", "Joe", "Emma"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add more names in "firstnames". Like if I want to add Gary the array would look like this: ["Jim", "Joe", "Emma", "Gary"].
I tried with the json module but it only rewrote it or added a new key

Comment: `I tried...` - where is it your code then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `append`:

```
d= {
"names": [
    {
      "firstnames": ["Jim", "Joe", "Emma"]
    }
  ]
}
d["names"][0]["firstnames"].append("Gary")
print(d)
# {'names': [{'firstnames': ['Jim', 'Joe', 'Emma', 'Gary']}]}
```

Comment: you can't assign the contents of a json file directly to d like that. you have to evaluate the content of the file. preferably with the json module. but the modification of d once properly loaded is correct

Comment: @steviestickman You're right, but those are two separate problems that should be addressed in two separate questions. If the OP is asking for help with both of those things at the same time, the question is too broad.